# How can I get the actual object name from within a Object Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

## Problem

I'm trying to figure out: how to `log` the actual object name from within the object prototype.

```js
Object.prototype.contentAndname = function() {
  console.log()//what should be getting logged is bikes
}

transportation = {
  automobile: {
    cars: {
      nissan: ["Altima", "Leaf"],
      tesla: ["Model S", "Model X"],
    },
    trucks: {
      ford: ["Super Duty", "F-150"],
      chevy: ["Silverado", "Colorado"],
    }
  },
  bikes: {
    cheap: ['homemade'],
    luxury: ['gucci']
  },
  legs: {
    human: [],
    dogs: [],
    cats: []
  }
}


transportation.bikes.contentAndname()
```

## Results I'm looking for

```js
Object.prototype.contentAndname = function() {
  // Code that figures out that the object being pass through is called bikes.
  
  console.log('bikes')//what should be getting logged is bikes
}

transportation = {
  automobile: {
    cars: {
      nissan: ["Altima", "Leaf"],
      tesla: ["Model S", "Model X"],
    },
    trucks: {
      ford: ["Super Duty", "F-150"],
      chevy: ["Silverado", "Colorado"],
    }
  },
  bikes: {
    cheap: ['homemade'],
    luxury: ['gucci']
  },
  legs: {
    human: [],
    dogs: [],
    cats: []
  }
}


transportation.bikes.contentAndname()
// I'm passing bikes through prototype
```

Comment: The object is just `{cheap: ['homemade'], luxury: ['gucci']}`. `bikes` is not part of the object. It's not sanely possible to reflect on what variable name (or property, same thing) the object is assigned to. It could be assigned to multiple names at the same time too.

Comment: hmn why you want to log the property name when you already write it down ?

Comment: Sorry… I'm still learning.

Comment: I'm creating… a new array base one the actual object

Comment: Also… How is this a duplicate? The link provided does not have the answer I want

Comment: Now… no one can answer the question.

Comment: you can iterate over `transportation` object's properties inside  your function using `for...in` and check if it matches with `this`. Then you'll get the name of the property used

Comment: Yes… but then I'll have to point it from a direction… It needs to be able to do it on its on. `Transportation` will be one of many variables. I won't be overwriting it or anything. Just reading it and using the name to create a new array in another variable.

Comment: But it only works if you know that it is `transportation` object's property and not `transportation` object's property's property like `cars` or `trucks`

Comment: Correct… it won't just be `transportation` object's property. It may be `plane` object's property or even `Submarine` object's property.

Comment: The duplicate may not have the answer you want, but that's because there is no solution. See my first comment, and the first paragraph of the accepted answer in the dupe.

Comment: So… instead of helping find another route, or letting someone else try to help me find another route. You put up a [duplicate], with a false link, and closed it from everybody? You could have done all of this with an answer, to let entry level coders know this.

Comment: What's "false" about the link?

Comment: [duplicate] means… this question was asked… here is the answer you were looking for. Then you just said `there is no solution`

Comment: There is no solution basically means… this is beyond my comprehension

Comment: … or I can't find another route for you to take. (So lets just close it)

Comment: You're not the first one to ask this question. The answer is always the same: *it's not sanely possible and you should rethink why you need this in the first place.* That's what "no solution" means.

Comment: To be clear, there are some limited situations in which iterating properties of `this` etc. might work; but there's absolutely no sane solution for situations like `function (bikes) { bikes.contentAndName(); }`. It just doesn't work like that, which is why you should first think about why you need this at all.